# Does Google Pub/Sub support transactional messaging?

Tags: transactions, google-cloud-pubsub

I know that [Kafka supports transactional messaging](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Transactional+Messaging+in+Kafka). I'm searching the internet for whether a similar feature is available in Google Pub/Sub. Surprisingly, I couldn't find any valuable materials, even in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs).

Comment: Generally, pub/sub does not lend itself to that. There may be multiple subscribers, or none at all. Transactions can be supported in a request/response scenario, though, where there's exactly one party on either end of the conversation.